# Changing the Android version from 2.2 to 2.1

Tags: android

I devloped an android app on `2.2`. I used the Soap webservices in my app through `https`.
I used `ssl` certification to access those services. It works fine in `version 2.2`, but now my client want it on `2.1`. So I changed the version and min sdk levels but when I run the app in 2.1 it gives me `SSl socket exception`. Now in my root folder of project it is showing `2.1` version. Could any one help me out?

Comment: now in your project root folder which android version was showing..?? 2.2.1 or 2.1.1??

Comment: are you using any libraries store in `lib`?

Comment: No Iam not using any libraries

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in android OS 2.1 to 2.2 that has to do with SSL certificates. But cannot find the url right now.

In order to avoid that you could catch the exception and on SSLException you could reconnect the server with a non-secure connection. Keeping a sharedpreference in case of exception for future use of non-secure connections will avoid double connections all the time.

It not so elegant or secure way but it works for me.